# Prove that $f(x) = 1$ for all $x ∈ [0, 1$] where $y = f(x$) satisfies the differential equation$ g(x)y'(x) + y(x) = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose that $g(0)=g(1)=0$ and that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at every point and $$) satisfies the differential equation $g(x)y′(x)+y(x)=1$ for all $x∈[0,1]$ . **Prove that $f(x)=1$ for all $x ∈ [0,1].$**

Am not quite sure on how to approach the question and would appreciate some help.

So far I know that because $g(0) = g(1$) and $f$ is differentiable, then for some $c ∈ [0,1]$ there exists $f'(c) = 0$, (by Rolle's Theorem).

Not quite sure how to handle the differential equation with this (assuming that's even the right approach).

Comment: "then for some c ∈ [0,1] there exists f '(c) = 0": no. Then for some c ∈ [0,1], (or "then there exists c ∈ [0,1] such that") g'(c) = 0.

Comment: Anyway, $g$ is not supposed to be differentiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting $x=0$ and $x=1$ in the DE we get $f(0)=f(1)=1$. Suppose $f(x) >1$ for some $x$. There is a point $x_0$ where $f$ attains its maximum. Since $f'(x_0)=0$ the DE gives $f(x_0)=1$, a contradiction (since the maximum value exceeds $1$). Similarly, $f(x)<1$ for some $x$ gives  a contradiction. Hence, $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.